# Very little oil, engine starts and there’s ticking, topped up with oil but the car loses power still. Is it fixable?

Tags: engine, oil, hyundai, damage, elantra

My 2018 Hyundai Elantra SE has been experiencing issues with losing power.  The engine started ticking this evening, and the vehicle was struggling to start. I managed to get home but we discovered it had a quart of oil and what it did have was really dirty. I’m terrified I’ve done damage to the engine because I’m awful at checking the oil. I originally thought it had battery issues but the oil light and check engine lights came on tonight. Topped off with 3 quarts of oil and the car is going on on Monday. What should I expect?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to say it, but when the oil is that low and it starts running bad, there's more than likely severe internal engine damage. Most likely you have done damage to the bearings, rings, and camshaft(s). The shop is most likely going to tell you a new engine is in store.

Comment: okay. so i could be looking at either heft repairs or a replacement. we ran a code and it did say the cam shaft sensor is bad. it sounded better than it did before we added the oil but it’s still having issues with losing power. going to have it towed to the shop on monday.

Comment: @Laura - Yah, unfortunately that will probably be the case ... however, when you take it in, do not suggest to them I gave you that advice. Just ask them to see what's wrong with it. If you go to the mechanic and tell them, "A guy said it was toast" ... they are sure to have you put a new engine in it.

Comment: I did not tell them any of the advice I received. My parents and myself have a very trustworthy mechanic and sadly, though the result is indeed an engine rebuild,  she’s going to do research and see what she can do to make it as cost efficient as she can. I guess Hyundai had a couple class action lawsuits filed against them for engine failure, so we’re gonna start there.